# Shall I take the cailed square root of n to test for a prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

Algorithm:

1. square root of $n$
2. test all primes lower than the square root of $n$ if they go evenly up into $n$; if not, $n$ is a prime

But do I have to take ceil$(n)$ or floor$(n)$ as the square root?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you asking about ceil$(\color{blue}{\sqrt n})$ vs. floor$(\color{blue}{\sqrt n})$?

Comment: and when you wrote "cailed" in the title, did you mean "ceil'ed"?

Answer (score 1):

Don't have to take the square root.

If you are testing a series of primes p,
stop when n/p < p.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for primes only up to floor$(\sqrt n)$.

That's because if $p>\sqrt n$ and $pq=n$, then $q<\sqrt n<p$,

so you would have found a factor of $n$ before you got up to testing $p$ dividing $n$.